# docx.js - cannot create document in landscape orientation

Tags: node.js, orientation, docx

I'm trying to generate .docx file using [docx](https://github.com/dolanmiu/docx) for JS/TS. I want to get a document in landscape orientation using [this example](https://runkit.com/dolanmiu/docx-demo7) from official documentation, but it not works. Result still in portrait orientation.

You can see it by press [endpoint](https://runkit.io/dolanmiu/docx-demo7/6.0.0) link in this example and view generated document.

Any ideas to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can make this work by using :

```
sections: [
    {
        properties: {
            page: {
                size: {
                    orientation: PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE,
                },
            },
        },
        children:[]
    }
}
```